# Sort columns by their single character names with vowels first

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5), columns=list('CBESA'))
df

    C   B   E   S   A
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

I want to rearrange the columns such that vowels come before consonants and alphabetically otherwise.

I can sort the columns alphabetically with `sort_index`

```
df.sort_index(1)

    A   B   C   E   S
0   4   1   0   2   3
1   9   6   5   7   8
2  14  11  10  12  13
3  19  16  15  17  18
4  24  21  20  22  23
```

But that leaves `'E'` out of order.
I can get what I want "manually"

```
df[list('AEBCS')]

    A   E   B   C   S
0   4   2   1   0   3
1   9   7   6   5   8
2  14  12  11  10  13
3  19  17  16  15  18
4  24  22  21  20  23
```

How do I do this dynamically considering I don't know the exact letters?  I do know that they are single character ascii capital letters.

Comment: You need to ask these earlier in the day.  At this point in the evening, these hurt my brain...

Comment: @StephenRauch very inconsiderate of me.

Comment: Did you missed `axis=1` in `df.sort_index()`?

Comment: @bro-grammer yes I did. thanks

Comment: @Downvoter, please explain how this is too broad. The question is perfectly on topic, and well explained. +1 from me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need `sorted` + `reindex`.

```
df.reindex(columns=[
    x[1] for x in sorted(zip(~df.columns.isin(list('AEIOU')), df.columns))
])
```

`sorted` will sort on multiple predicates if you pass it a list/container of tuples generated with `zip`.

Alternatively, adopting piR's suggestion and using a `lambda` to sort:

```
df.reindex(
    columns=sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: (x not in 'AEIOU', x))
)
```

```
    A   E   B   C   S
0   4   2   1   0   3
1   9   7   6   5   8
2  14  12  11  10  13
3  19  17  16  15  18
4  24  22  21  20  23
```

Comment: I like it.  Different from I was thinking.

Comment: `sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: (x not in 'AEIOU', x))`